# Using sql tableadapters to update database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am building an application for a group of friends and myself to use for DnD sessions. Part of the program involves taking all of the values that are entered for our characters, items, etc and storing them to a database. I have the database built, and am pulling from the database into the program, however I am unable to return data to the database. I have the data coming into a dataset, and all of my edits are affecting the dataset, but I cannot get anything to affect the actual source database tables.

Below I have the button that I intend to use to update items in the characters' packs. I have both dataadapter, and tableadapter methods included that I have tried.

---

```
 private void btnaddpack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbxpack.Text != "")
        {
            /*connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Pack SET Item = (@ItemName)" + "WHERE Id = '" + this.lstpack.SelectedValue + "';";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();*/

            string packitem = txtbxpack.Text;    //will take item from an textbox
            this.packTableAdapter.Insert(packitem);

            this.Validate();
            this.packBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.packTableAdapter.Update(this.dnD_MachineDataSet.Pack);
        }


        PopulatePack();
```

---

Here is my populate code in case someone needs that:

```
private void PopulatePack()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))    //this is all about opening the connection to the sqldatabase, normally it would need to be closed, but this uses idisposable, so it will close itself
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Pack", connection))
        {


            DataTable packtable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(packtable);

            lstpack.DataSource = packtable;
            lstpack.DisplayMember = "Item";
            lstpack.ValueMember = "Id";

        }


    }
```

As mentioned above, all of the changes are appearing whenever I re-populate the listboxes that draw upon the dataset, hence why this is an issue of trying to get that data back into the source database. I will make the obligatory "I'm relatively new to using databases" statement as it will do no good to pretend that I am an expert.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't sql server kind of pricey for a dnd app? Also a little overkill. If your just doing it to learn I understand, but have you considered a free database or even better some text files to write the information too?

Comment: It mainly is an excuse for me to learn to do it and to have an actual use for it once completed. As for price, not an issue what with express versions of sql on the market. Text files were the original thought, but once again, figured I would try to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

In the commented code, you would need to do the following:

1. assign the connection object to the SqlCommand object's Connection
   property
2. pass the item name to your @ItemName parameter
3. assign a parameter value to the 'Id' column in the WHERE clause
4. remove, 'cmd.Clone();', and replace with, 'connection.Close();'

Here is what the code should look like:

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Pack SET Item = (@ItemName) WHERE Id = @ID;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", txtbxpack.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this.lstpack.SelectedValue);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just added this in and worked around with it, I am observing the same behavior where everything will update in the app, however when I check the table it remains empty. I tied the connection to my connectionstring. Is there anything that would affect this since I am currently using the sql tools built into VS15, or should that not matter?

Comment: Although, interestingly enough, despite the tables appearing to be empty, the data appears to be storing now. I have cleared everything from the app out of memory on my main workstation and it still remembers the values. Also moved to a different workstation and it still held the data...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by tables appearing to be empty, but data appears to store.  Does it save the item? If you close your app and restart it, does it display the saved value, or the original value?

Comment: When I query the tables (pack table(select * from...)) there is nothing in the table. However after restarting the program, the newly added value appears correctly, and if I move the program to a different computer, the saved value also shows up correctly. This does appear to work now, I just find it odd that the database table would appear empty if it is holding data now, and that led to some confusion on my part.

Comment: Does your query have a WHERE clause?  If so, you may be using a value that doesn't match any of the values for the column you are filtering?  Suggest you check your SELECT without a WHERE clause to see everything.

Comment: Select * from Pack, is the query.

Comment: Are you querying in VS or SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: VS, that is where the tables/database was created as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think VS created a separate database instance where the table is empty.  In the VS menu select 'VIEW', 'SQL Server Object Explorer'.  If you iterate through the many instances of SQL Server Services running on your machine, you'll likely see a 2nd copy of your database somewhere!

Comment: That is exactly it, it currently has three instances of the database showing. I had heard rumor that this was a thing that VS did, something about data integrity or something of that sort. Would you happen to know how I would query the databases? I appreciate all of the help btw.

Comment: You can right-click on a database and select, 'New Query...'
Or, (even easier!) just right-click on the table in the database and select, 'View Data'!